# Creating dynamic split functionality using sliders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slider

Currently I'm creating an application where the user can split the bill to individual candidates. Initially the slider values are equal for all candidates and the user can adjust them on the page accordingly where to increase someone's percentage, they have to decrease someone else's first. If the total amount of all sliders equal to 100, the sliders cannot move further which I'm achieving using `upperLimit` in the [slider library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider)

So far I've been able to achieve this with 2 users where I basically hardcoded the states and the logic by saying if when slider 1 is moved and `state1 + state2 < 101` then pass the value `100 - (slider 1 value)` to the slider 2 value. I'm achieving this with the following code:

```
const SplitBillPage = () => {
  const splitUsers = 2;
  const equalValueSplit = 100 / splitUsers;
  const [range, setRange] = useState(equalValueSplit + '%');
  const [secondRange, setSecondRange] = useState(equalValueSplit + '%');
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(100);
  const [limitSecond, setLimitSecond] = useState(100);

  function rangeSetter(value) {
    setRange(parseInt(value) + '%');
    let x = range;
    let y = secondRange;
    let withoutPercentage = x.replace('%', '');
    let withoutPercentageSecond = y.replace('%', '');
    let valueLimit = 100 - parseInt(withoutPercentage);
    if (parseInt(withoutPercentage) + parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond) < 101) {
      setLimitSecond(valueLimit);
    }
  }

  function rangeSetterSecond(value) {
    setSecondRange(parseInt(value) + '%');
    let x = range;
    let y = secondRange;
    let withoutPercentage = x.replace('%', '');
    let withoutPercentageSecond = y.replace('%', '');
    let valueLimit = 100 - parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond);
    if (parseInt(withoutPercentage) + parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond) < 101) {
      setLimit(valueLimit);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{range}</Text>
      <Slider
        minimumValue={0}
        value={equalValueSplit}
        maximumValue={100}
        upperLimit={limit}
        onValueChange={value => rangeSetter(value)}
      />
      <Text>{secondRange}</Text>
      <Slider
        minimumValue={0}
        value={equalValueSplit}
        maximumValue={100}
        upperLimit={limitSecond}
        onValueChange={value => rangeSetterSecond(value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SplitBillPage;
```

Now I'm confused on how to create the logic when the number increases above 2. Here I've used 1 states for each user which are `limit` and `limitSecond`, but this doesnt seem efficient when I've 10 users and me creating an individual state for each of them and the using `state1 +state2 + ... <101`.

So I need a way to solve this logic when the number increases from 2.

Comment: do you expect the reduction in one slider to be equally split between all other sliders?

Comment: @pilchard yea so suppose there are 3 sliders and slider 1 reduces by 10 points, then the user has the option to adjust +10 in the other 2 sliders. It can be 5 in slider 2 and 5 in slider 3 or 10 in slider 2 and 0 in slider 3